# Geometric Picard group of a semi-abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Fix a number field $k$ and consider a smooth projective geometrically connected $k$-curve $C$, with a $k$-rational divisor class of degree one inducing the embedding into its Jacobian $J$. For any dense open subscheme of $C$, its complement of degree $d$ corresponds to a semi-abelian variety $S$ sitting in the middle of the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow T \rightarrow S \rightarrow J \rightarrow 0$$
where $T$ is a torus of dimension $d-1$. $S$ is called the generalized Jacobian of $C$.

Is it possible that the geometric Picard groups of $S$ and $J$ are isomorphic? In other words, does the surjective morphism $S \rightarrow J$ induce an isomorphism $\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{J}) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathrm{Pic}(\bar{S})$?

Intuitively I think this is true because a line bundle on $\bar{T}$ is trivial and so line bundles on $\bar{S}$ correspond to line bundles on $\bar{J}$ but I am not sure how to make this concrete.